# How to get elements by a specific value of a custom attribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can you tell me how can I get all `<input>` fields with custom "validation" attribute.

```html
<form>
    <p><input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" validation="isRequired,currectFormat" placeholder="first name" required/></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" validation="isRequired,currectFormat" placeholder="last name"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="email" name="email" validation="isRequired,currectFormat" placeholder="email"/></p>
    <p><input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="address" /></p>
    <input type="button" value="OK">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var inputs  = document.querySelectorAll('form input[validation]');
```

use css attribute selectors in `querySelectorAll()`.

https://jsfiddle.net/hkcmrLer/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[validation="isRequired,currentFormat"]');
```